# Creating line feature with multiple record

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes, feature-class

I am trying to create line feature with multiple record in ArcGIS 10.8. Actually I am working on FTTH project there I need to draw 12 f fiber which single cable contains 12 separate threads in it and there is different attributes for every thread. First option is that I should create 12 line for every thread but it is not applicable. I have to draw single line and need to manage 12 threads in attribute.

Comment: It is normal to have multiple attributes for a single polyline, what kind of attributes are you looking to store for each thread? If you need a lot of attributes for each thread you might need a dedicated utility product like ArcFM to keep track or have a one-to-many relate with a database having an entry for each thread related by a common line-table attribute value. Have a read of https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-attributes/about-editing-relationships-in-arcmap.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_940A229C62924DCDACBB195142EE080E about relates

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create several records in table of contents that points to the same feature; the opposite is possible.
However you can create another table and with relationships, you can point several records on the same line.

So you must take a look at the geodatabase, tables and relationships.